# Ftp Connection Failure in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ftp

Using the code below, I continue to get a "Unable to connect to the remote server" error at `Using response as..`. I'm not quite sure whats wrong or where to look for help. FTP in .NET seems to be seldom used.

Ok, second stupid question. EnableSsl != Sftp?

```
    Dim FTPrequest As FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(FtpWebRequest.Create(New Uri("ftp://176.31.212.85/dev/shm/Minecraft/world/players/Drise.dat")), FtpWebRequest)
    FTPrequest.EnableSsl = True
    FTPrequest.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "pass")
    FTPrequest.Method = Ftp.DownloadFile
    FTPrequest.UseBinary = True
    FTPrequest.KeepAlive = False
    Dim ftpstream As IO.Stream = Nothing

    Using response As System.Net.FtpWebResponse = CType(FTPrequest.GetResponse(), System.Net.FtpWebResponse)
        Using responseStream As IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream
            'loop to read & write to stream
            Dim buffer(2047) As Byte
            Dim read As Integer = 0
            Do
                read = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, read)
            Loop Until read = 0 'see Note(1)
            responseStream.Close()
        End Using
        response.Close()
    End Using
```

Comment: Have you checked external factors such as firewall, security policy, etc?

Comment: I connect with the same credentials with FileZilla and it connects fine. If that's what you are asking.

Comment: Sort of. The firewall in windows can discriminate based on the name of the app, for example, and ftp has both passive and active modes that can hit different ports and therefore trip firewall in different ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to provide some clarification I found later in regards to this question that I never got to posting. SFTP is part of the SSH family, not, SSL. VB.Net (since the last time I used it) does not support SFTP connections. There are some external libraries that do, but all of the ones I found required money.